# c# How to return a list through a class return?

Tags: c#, forms, list, return

I've got a list in a class that I'm trying to return to view on a form but I cant return it from the class, How would I do this?

On the class:

```
private List<Module> modules;

public void AddModule(Module add)
{
    modules.Add(add);
}

public List Modules
{
    get { return modules; }
}
```

On the form:

```
moduleTitleLabel.Text = cnet.Title;

stgOne.AddModule(cnet);

moduleList.DataSource = stgOne.Modules;
```

I get an error on the List on the return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datatypes are different:

```
private List<Module> modules;

public void AddModule(Module add)
{
    modules.Add(add);
}

// this one should be generic too
public List<Module> Modules
{
    get { return modules; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing generic type argument, it should be:

```
public List<Module> Modules
{
    get { return modules; }
}
```